# javascript to run onload and onchange

Tags: javascript, onload, onchange

I have a javascript that runs using the onchange event when a user enteres a value into an input box.

The script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  function showUser(userNumber, str)  
  {  
    if (str=="")  
    {  
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML="";  
      return;  
    }    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari  
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    }  

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  
    {  
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  
      {  
        //document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
        var responseText = xmlhttp.responseText; 
        var description = responseText; 
        var warehouse = ""; 
        var sellingUnits = ""; 
        if (responseText.indexOf("NOT A VALID") == -1) 
        { 
          description = responseText.substring(12, responseText.indexOf(",Warehouse:"));  
          warehouse = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",Warehouse:")+11, responseText.indexOf(",SellingUnits:"));  
          sellingUnits = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",SellingUnits:")+14);  
        } 

        document.getElementById("whse" + userNumber).innerHTML = warehouse;  
        document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML = description;  
        document.getElementById("su" + userNumber).innerHTML = sellingUnits; 

      }  
    }  
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true);  
    xmlhttp.send(); 
  } 
</script>
```

and the form is

```
<form name="orderform" id="orderform" action="newsale.php" method="post">

<table border=1>    

<tr>
<td>Product Code</td>
<td>Description</td>
<td>Warehouse</td>
<td>Selling Units</td>
</tr>
<tr id="r1">  
    <td width=100>
        <input size=10  type=number id=sku1 name=sku1 value="1182" onchange="showUser(1, this.value)">
    </td>
    <td width=280>
        <div align="left" id="txtHint1">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td width=100>
        <div align="left" id="whse1">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td width=100>
        <div align="left" id="su1">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r2">  
    <td>
        <input size=10  type=number id=sku2 name=sku2 value="1183" onchange="showUser(2, this.value)">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="txtHint2">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="whse2">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td width=100>
        <div align="left" id="su2">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r3">  
    <td>
        <input size=10  type=number id=sku3 name=sku3 value="1174" onchange="showUser(3, this.value)">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="txtHint3">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="whse3">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td width=100>
        <div align="left" id="su3">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="r4">  
    <td>
        <input size=10  type=number id=sku4 name=sku4 value="1046" onchange="showUser(4, this.value)">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="txtHint4">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div align="left" id="whse4">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
    <td width=100>
        <div align="left" id="su4">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

So as mentioned, the script works perfectly for the onchange event. I have defined values for each input box, when the page loads I want the script to be called and executed for those values. Once the user changes the values it must rerun for the new value.

I tried putting the following script in the header section of the page, but it is inconsistent in the rows it works for. My skills arent great so I feel I am missing something small.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
window.onload = function() { 
showUser(1, document.getElementById("sku1").value);
showUser(2, document.getElementById("sku2").value);
showUser(3, document.getElementById("sku3").value);
showUser(4, document.getElementById("sku4").value);
}
</script>
```

Any advice is appreciated as always.
Thanks and Regards,
Ryan

Comment: [jQuery](http://jquery.com) could make your life a bit easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long shot, try this in your existing code. Declare xmlhttp as a local variable to the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  function showUser(userNumber, str)  
  {  

    var xmlhttp = null; // line aded.
    if (str=="")  
    {  
      document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML="";  
      return;  
    }    
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari  
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    }  

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  
    {  
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)  
      {  
        //document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
        var responseText = xmlhttp.responseText; 
        var description = responseText; 
        var warehouse = ""; 
        var sellingUnits = ""; 
        if (responseText.indexOf("NOT A VALID") == -1) 
        { 
          description = responseText.substring(12, responseText.indexOf(",Warehouse:"));  
          warehouse = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",Warehouse:")+11, responseText.indexOf(",SellingUnits:"));  
          sellingUnits = responseText.substring(responseText.indexOf(",SellingUnits:")+14);  
        } 

        document.getElementById("whse" + userNumber).innerHTML = warehouse;  
        document.getElementById("txtHint" + userNumber).innerHTML = description;  
        document.getElementById("su" + userNumber).innerHTML = sellingUnits; 

      }  
    }  
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q="+str,true);  
    xmlhttp.send(); 
  } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the script at the bottom, just before the closing body tag.
You could also consider using jQuery and then use the $(document).ready

**EDIT:** I meant the last script in your question

Comment: Hi @Bart, Thanks for the prompt feedback. I placed the last script in the question before the </body> tag and it has the same result. the page is inconsistent with the output and the scripts that are run 'onload'.  Personally I dont think the last script is 100% correct as the first two rows are never populated whilst the last two are inconsistent. Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: window.onload may be called too early. Consider jQuery and the $(document).ready function.

Comment: It looks like it is firing too early and the DOM is not ready.
If you use jQuery, you also can get rid of handling AJAX calls yourself and all the getElementbyId's